# How can I replace a complete project terrain by another one in unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've completed a project recently. But now I want to change the terrain of the project. I already created a new terrain now ready to replace the project terrain by this.I've tried several hours but can't do that. How to replace the terrain by a new one. Please help me by details one. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you duplicate your Terrain data with CTRL+D and then paste it on the scene you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be much simpler to just duplicate the original terrain GameObject and then edit it so it to be as the new terrain you wanted.
In order to duplicate the original terrain object, just select it and press CTLR+D.